# Prefilled Search Box Using PHP/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search field on a page that allows users to search for a certain record.

I have a PHP file that displays all records and has a search box at the top using Jquery to filter results as a user types it in. I want to send the user's search results from the previous page to the search box so that their results are already filtered to their search term.

I was able to bring over the search term using this code for the search box:

```
        <input type="text" id="filtersearch" placeholder="Search by name or phone number" value="<?php echo $search; ?>">
```

But while it transfers the search field, the results aren't filtered when the page is opened. You have to click on the search box and hit enter for it to update the results.

This is the script I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $rows = $('#orders tbody tr');
$('#filtersearch').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, is there any way to limit the filtering on the search to just certain fields or columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the results on page load, you can just trigger a key up event on the element on document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $rows = $('#orders tbody tr');
    $('#filtersearch').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
    $('#filtersearch').keyup();
});
```

In order to limit the search, you just need to limit the selector for `$rows`.  For example, if you just want to apply a `filterable` class to cells in individual columns and only search those columns you could adjust your `$rows` declaration like this:

```
var $rows = $('#orders tbody .filterable');
```

And if you want to hide rows based on those results, you would need to find the parent row for the `td.filterable` to hide, so you would need to adjust your hide line of code to find the closest `tr` like this:

```
       $rows.closest('tr').show().end().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).closest('tr').hide();
```

Though in doing so, you might want to change the name of the variable since it is no longer tied to just "rows". I just kept the variable name the same here so you can see only those changes in code needed to make this work.